# Разница между и примение слов "законный" и "легальный"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, выбор-варианта

Объясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях следует использовать слово "законный", а в каких — "легальный".

Пример из жизни: есть сайты, где можно посмотреть фильмы, не скачивая их. Ну типа Netflix. Некоторы из этих сайтов — пиратские, а некоторые (тот самый Neflix, например) — непиратские, "официальные". Так вот, в отношении вторых, какое слово лучше подойдёт, "законнные" или "легальные" ("законные онлайн-кинотеатры", "легальные онлайн-кинотеатры")?

Слово "законные" для меня звучит крайне неуместно, хотя объяснить эту неуместность с точки зрения логики у меня не получается.

Я сейчас вообще не вижу смысла в использовании в русском языке слова "легальный". Зачем, если есть "законный"?

Comment: Этимологический словарь Крылова: *легальный* — это слово, имеющее значение "разрешаемый законом", восходит (через французское посредство) к латинскому lex ("закон") и означает буквально "законный".

Answer (score 2):

Есть небольшая разница в значениях:
*легальный* — разрешённый;
*законный* — который соответствует закону.

Стилистика:

Кинотеатры не могут соответствовать закону (нарушение стилистики, режет слух), поэтому подходит только слово "легальный". Другое дело "деятельность":
*Деятельность этого кинотеатра абсолютно законна.*

Слово "законный" больше используется в юриспруденции, примеры из БТС:
*Законный наследник.

Законные финансовые операции.

Дать делу законный ход.

Совершить сделку на законном основании.

Законный брак.*
Как видим, оно удачно, когда говорим о чём-то абстрактном или о лице (кинотеатры сюда не относятся).

Answer (score 1):

> Объясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях следует использовать слово
> "законный", а в каких — "легальный".

В русский язык слово *"легальный"* пришло в XIX в. в своем первоначальном значении. Слово имеет латинское происхождение, означает и является полным синонимом слову *"законный"*.

> Я сейчас вообще не вижу смысла в использовании в русском языке слова
> "легальный". Зачем, если есть "законный"?

Трансформация языка и включение в него новых слов из других культур – естественный процесс.
Немотивированное использование заимствований называется языковой модой.

> Так вот, в отношении вторых, какое слово лучше подойдёт, "законнные"
> или "легальные" ("законные онлайн-кинотеатры", "легальные
> онлайн-кинотеатры")?

Какое слово лучше подойдет каждый решает для себя сам.

Comment: *Какое слово лучше подойдет каждый решает для себя сам* — когда корректны оба варианта (такое далеко не всегда), всегда есть лучший, и не каждый может определить какой.